# PHP a href link with print or echo don't work

Tags: php, html

I have question about a href link in php field. When I try to make a href link in php field by using echo or print, when i click the link it does not work the link. Could you see the code briefly? Thanks!

```html
<?php
                    if (isset($_SESSION['name1'])) {
                     
                     echo '<li class="dropdown">'; 
                     echo '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">';
                     echo "Hi,";
                     echo $_SESSION['name1']; 
                     echo '<span class="caret"></span></a>';
                     echo '<ul id="logout-dp" class="dropdown-menu">';
                     echo  '<li>';
                     echo   '<div class="row">';
                     echo    '<div class="col-md-12">';
                     echo     '<div class="form-group">';
                     echo      '<ul>';
                     echo       '<li><div><a class="col" href="logout.php">Logout</a></div></li>';
                     echo       '<li><div><a class="col" href="#">Account</a></div></li>';
                     echo       '<li><div><a class="col" href="resetpassword.php">Reset password</a></div></li>';
                     echo      '</ul>';                           
                     echo     '</div>';
                     echo    '</div>';
                     echo   '</div>';
           echo  '</li>'; 
       echo '</ul>'; 
       echo '</li>';                        
                    }
?>
```

Comment: which link not working for you

Comment: logout, resetpassword

Comment: What does not work? You land on the wrong page (if so, what page you land on)? Your logout and reserpassword files have errors?

Comment: No..................

Answer (score 0):

Your code is delimiting quotes which is not needed as you are using a different set of quotes to encapsulate the string already.

Change:

```
'<li><div><a class="col" href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a></div></li>';
```

to:

```
'<li><div><a class="col" href="logout.php">Logout</a></div></li>';
```

This should have stuck out if you inspected the source code you were outputting as then showing the following:

```
<a class="col" href=\"logout.php\">Logout</a>
```

Which is clearly not a valid hyperlink.

Edit: Your code in the question has now changed to remove the `\"`. Not sure if that was you or someone "correcting" the question.

Answer (score 0):

i modified your code because it was really difficult to follow with all those `echo` calls.

also made the logout and resetpass links point to the root of the domain, which is where i assume you have them.
ex. domain.com/logout.php and domain.com/resetpassword.php

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['name1'])) {
        echo '<li class="dropdown">' .  
        '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">' . 
        "Hi," . 
        $_SESSION['name1'] .  
        '<span class="caret"></span></a>' . 
        '<ul id="logout-dp" class="dropdown-menu">' . 
         '<li>' . 
          '<div class="row">' . 
           '<div class="col-md-12">' . 
            '<div class="form-group">' . 
             '<ul>' . 
              '<li><div><a class="col" href="logout.php">Logout</a></div></li>' . 
              '<li><div><a class="col" href="#">Account</a></div></li>' . 
              '<li><div><a class="col" href="resetpassword.php">Reset password</a></div></li>' . 
             '</ul>' .                            
            '</div>' . 
           '</div>' . 
          '</div>' . 
         '</li>' .  
        '</ul>' .  
        '</li>';                        
    }
```

Comment: can you give more details as to what is not working? you cannot click on the link, does the link appear, when you click it gives you a 404 not found?

Comment: If i clicking that href nothing to happen... but its working in home.php

Comment: please post the full url of logout.php, ex. `domain.com/logout.php` or `domain.com/dir/logout.php`

Comment: H2O/php/logout.php.. but account.php file in H2O/php

Comment: edited my answer according to your file structure. it will work if home.php is in the same directory `H2O/php/`

Comment: No.. home.php in H2O/home.php

Comment: How to get console.log for that line